# Eclipse searches in some other irrelevant R.java class for id's

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

When in the middle of developing a small app, I noticed that Eclipse searches in some other R.java instead of the R.java file in my project.

Ex : I created a TextView (`android:id="@+id/title"`).
When I tried to access it through my class (by using `findViewById(R.id.title)`), it showed some other R.java class which contained some id's I've never even used and doesn't contain the "title" id I gave my TextView. 
When I checked my `R.java` class, it's absolutely fine (there's the "title" id in it). And when I gave `findViewById(my.package.R.id.title)` instead of `findViewById(R.id.title)`, it works fine.

Anybody know why?
PS : I tried cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse. Didn't work.

Comment: which r did you import? remove `import android.R;` if you have that

Comment: I recommend to neither use single-seater class names nor class names that are used elsewhere already.

Comment: As usual, stupid mistake again. Thanks @Raghunandan. I imported the correct one and it works fine now

Comment: You don't even need to import it. It's added automatically. Only never make the mistake and import android.R; as Raghunandan mentioned.